# Getting thread's backtrace in java (android) from its thread id

Tags: android, debugging, adb, dalvik

Is it possible to print backtrace of a thread ( I have thread id and process id ) from adb shell /or by any other method without modifying the code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- Attach a debugger (if the app is debuggable).
- Attach DDMS and examine the Threads tab (if the app is debuggable).
- Send the process a SIGQUIT, with `adb shell kill -3 <pid>`, to dump the stack trace into the ANR trace log (if your device is rooted).